# jquery drag and drop list items via ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, highcharts, drag-and-drop

I came to know that jquery drag and drop can't be done on select drop down. So I made a dropdown with `<ul> <li>`  items. When I drag a list item, I need to display the respective highchart via ajax loading. but am only able to display the chart on one div. i need to display the list item's respective chart (via ajax)on each div based on the selected list item.

You can find the code here..! http://jsfiddle.net/J2vHu/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use the same parameter for each chart (renderTo parameter) which means that you always setup chart in the first div.

```
$(".target").droppable({
        accept: ".reports",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault;
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            loadChart(id);
            $(".target").append(chart);
        }
    });
```

and ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/data1/[40,20,30]/data2/[15,2,30]/data3/[10,,40,50]",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsondata) {
            options.chart.renderTo = id;
            options.series[0].data = jsondata.data1;
            options.series[1].data = jsondata.data2;
            options.series[2].data = jsondata.data3;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, error, errorThrown) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/J2vHu/20/

Comment: @Bochan..! I was dragging multiple items in to dynamic div, Once the item is dragged on a div and if we try to drag the same item on the same div, it should restrict the other item to be dragged. i need to show something like its already dragged. how can i do this.  refer [http://jsfiddle.net/J2vHu/22/]